# How to call javafx class from java class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have called from my java class another javafx class as a background thread.

```
     while(true)
     {
    ....
    .... (build new arguments)
    ....

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            ChartData.main(arguments);
        }
    };
    t.start();
    }
```

I get an ERROR:

> Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once
>       at om.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:94)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:75)
>       at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:209)

with `javafx` class I have constructed only a scatterplot and 
all my other objects have been achieved in `java` class.

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way JavaFX works.

You have 2 options:

1. make your program a proper JavaFX application, and just update the content of your drawing, GUI, or whatever. (You don't need an extra thread for this: just submit something to the UI thread with invokeLater.)
2. Instead of a thread, run the separate JavaFX in its own process, see ProcessBuilder. Though this is more clean, you'll have to think abvout how to pass the data to show to the process

Comment: third option: use local network connection between the java application and javafx application.

Comment: Thank you Ingo, if I correctly understand, I have to start my javafx class such as: `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("command", "The first argument", "TheSecondWithoutSpace");` ...Right?